# Comparing a Date from an SQLite Database to the current DateTime in C#, Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, datetime, xamarin, compare

So I have generated a SQLite database in Xamarin Forms. Each item has a Name and Date. I'm trying to extract the date and set it to a variable so that when each item is loaded, it will convert its date integer to DateTime and compare it to DateTime.Now.
I'm not sure how to do this, and I might be missing something very elementary- I'm a complete beginner.

```
public LivePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            
            LiveService.AddLive("2022年3月19日（土）: ILLUSION FORCE presents「ILLUSION FORCE×GAUNTLET LONGSTAGE 'GACHINKO'2MAN GIG」", 20220319);
            LiveService.AddLive("2022年3月20日（日）Phantom Excaliver presents 聖剣フェス」", 202203020);
            LiveService.AddLive("2022年4月2日（土）Bad Company vol.17」", 20220402);
            LiveService.AddLive("2022年4月10日（日）VELL'z FIRE presents", 20220410);
            LiveService.AddLive("2022年4月10日（日）ILLUSION FORCE presents「ILLUSION FORCE×Amiliyah LONG STAGE 2MAN GIG」", 20220410);
            LiveService.AddLive("2022年4月29日（金・祝）渋谷メタル会 presents 渋谷メタル会フェス 2022」", 20220429);
            var Lists = LiveService.db.Table<Live>().ToList();
            MainListView.ItemsSource = Lists;
            int dateInt = Lists[2];
            DateTime dater = Convert.ToDateTime(dateInt);
            int result = DateTime.Compare(dater, DateTime.Now);
            if (result < 0)
            {
                Label.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Strikethrough;
            }
```

How I created the Table

```
namespace IF2.Models
{
    public class Live
    {

    public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }


    }

}
```

Service File

```
public static SQLiteConnection db;

        static void Init()
        {
            
            if (db != null)
                return;

            // Get an absolute path to the database file
            var databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Lives.db3");

            db = new SQLiteConnection(databasePath);
            db.DropTable<Live>();
            db.CreateTable<Live>();
        }

        public static void AddLive(string name, string date)
        {
            Init();
         
            var live = new Live
            {
                Name = name,
                Date = date,
                
            };

            var id = db.Insert(live);
        }
        public static void GetProperties()
        {
            Init();
            var Lists = db.Table<Live>().ToList();
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something, but if you have the date stored in the DB Table as a `DateTime`… then what are you trying to “convert?” In my small tests the convert code … `DateTime dater = Convert.ToDateTime(dateInt);` … throws an invalid cast exception as the documentation shows. It is unclear what you want to convert from and to.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity.
The Date is set as an integer (20220518) for example. I want to convert that to DateTime. The conversion itself is typically no problem, I just seem to be unable to extract the integer and set it to int dateInt

Comment: Thanks for responding
"And if so, can you change it to a DATE TIME field"
That's my whole issue. I don't know the code to use to assign the Date integer to a something. like (dateToConvert = Date)
I tried with "int dateInt = Lists[2];" but that doesn't work- it gives me CS0029, cannot convert type "" to int.
I just don't know how to grab the Date integer and do things to it.
Ideally I can just reference the value of the Date Column for a row, convert it to DateTime and compare it to DateTimeNow. But I can't get past the first step.

Comment: That's totally fine and all- I can change the int to a DateTime type column instead no problem. My problem is I don't know the code to use said data (even if I change it to DateTime). I don't know the code to parse and grab the value. so I can assign something to it. Sorry if my explanations were poorly worded. It's not the format of being int or DateTime or the conversion from one to the other that's bothering me, so I should have rephrased my question in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `public static void AddLive(string name, string date)`, you set the type of the date as string.

At first, try to get the data list, because there isn't only one line data in the table.

```
var stringlist = new List<string>()
// var intlist = new List<int>()
foreach(item in Lists)
{
  var live = item as Live()
  list.Add(live.Date)
 //intlist.Add(int.Parse(live.Date))
}
```

Get the date time now:

```
string nowTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
// and the value of the string will be like "20220322"
```

And then you can compare them with the "==" such as:

```
var value = (nowTime == stringlist[i])
```

You can also compare them in the `foreach(item in Lists)` and needn't to get the list of the date.

Create a model class as a table. You need to give it a primary key and the attribute named table.

```
 [Table("Live")]
public class Live

{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: @OllieOllieOllie  Can you show how you create the table named Live and how you display the date in your xaml?

Comment: Thank you for your continued help
I added the code used in my original comment- as of now, I made Date a string, but it could be either. The date is actually not displayed in my UI at all- I only meant to use it to compare it to the current date and strike out the ListItem text if it was earlier than.

Comment: I had edited my answer and you can try it. @OllieOllieOllie

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? @OllieOllieOllie

Comment: Hey thanks once again- I tried it out and it had crashed my app- I'll have to play with it a bit more first and then I'll get back to you!

Comment: I had checked your code again, and found that there is something wrong in your model class. You can check the edit answer. @OllieOllieOllie

Comment: I'm afraid that
var value = (nowTime == stringlist[i]);
or a variation of it using int
int result = DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(i), DateTime.Now);
is giving me an invalid cast exception error and not loading the app

Comment: Had you get the value with `string nowTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);`?  You can print it after get it and you can print the stringlist and check what's value in it. @OllieOllieOllie

Comment: Unfortunately, using that still gives me the same error when comparing it to stringlist thought that code itself is fine

Comment: You can check what is in the list at first, just use `Console.WriteLine(stringlist[0]);` to see what the value is in the stringlist.@OllieOllieOllie

Comment: Ok that absolutely worked!!!!! Wow! It showed the correct date (20220319)
so the list absolutely worked-
Now I just have to figure out why it's crashing when it's being compared!

Comment: I find a way to make it work with your methods- 
What I have now is really long and obfuscated- But it checks out
My next step is to figure out how to use that comparison to strikethrough or not strikethrough the text of each label in the listview, but you have answered the question! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I had to delete my previous comments. I was mistaken about SQLite being able to cast the date data as a `DateTime` object. Therefore, I can throw out a simple parser that will convert the `string` value of the date data.

If the data is bad then today’s date is returned, however you could return any date. You could use it like…

```
DateTime dater = GetDTFromString(dateInt.ToString());
```

The parser...

```
private DateTime GetDTFromString(string dateString) {
  if (dateString.Length >= 8) {
    string year = dateString.Substring(0, 4);
    string month = dateString.Substring(4, 2);
    string day = dateString.Substring(6, 2);
    if (DateTime.TryParse(year + "," + month + "," + day, out DateTime targetDate)) {
      return targetDate;
    }
  }
  return DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.
This, as well as Liyun Zhang's answer should definitely get me the data I'm looking for from my database to be used as I'd like. 
But it seems that it doesn't- I assume because each row is being inserted into a ListView in xamarin within this method- so even with this parser, I don't see how to apply a convert, compare, and finally do a strikethrough for each row's date depending on the results. I'm not sure of even how to think about this problem now. But really, thank you